# Can't connect to a remote debugger on Docker from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose, sitecore

I have a Docker Composer that looks like:

```
    version: '2.4'

services:

  sql:
    image: sitecore-xm1-sxa-1.9.0-sqldev:9.2.0-windowsservercore-${windows_version}
    volumes:
      - .\build\data\sql:C:\Data
    mem_limit: 2GB
    ports:
      - "44010:1433"

  cd:
    image: sitecore-xm1-sxa-1.9.0-cd:9.2.0-windowsservercore-${windows_version}
    volumes:
      -  .\build\data\cd:C:\inetpub\sc\App_Data\logs
      -  .\build\Website:C:\src
      -  d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger:C:\remote_debugger:ro
      -  .\src:c:\unicorn\
      -  .\docker-specific-files:c:\docker-specific-files
    ports:
      - "44002:80"
    expose:
      - "4023"
      - "4022"
      - "4021"
      - "4020"      
    links:
      - sql
    entrypoint: cmd /c "start /B powershell C:/sitecore/scripts/Watch-Directory.ps1 C:/src C:\inetpub\sc & powershell C:/sitecore/scripts/Watch-Directory.ps1 C:/docker-specific-files C:\inetpub\sc -ExcludeFiles @('Web.config','ConnectionStrings.config') & C:\\remote_debugger\\x64\\msvsmon.exe /noauth /anyuser /silent /nostatus /noclrwarn /nosecuritywarn /nofirewallwarn /nowowwarn /timeout:2147483646"

  cm:
    image: registry.valtech.dk/sitecore-xm1-sxa-1.9.0-cm:9.2.0-windowsservercore-${windows_version}
    volumes:
      -  .\build\data\cm:C:\inetpub\sc\App_Data\logs
      -  .\build\Website:C:\src
      -  .\docker-specific-files:c:\docker-specific-files
      -  .\src:c:\unicorn\
      -  d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger:C:\remote_debugger:ro
    ports:
      - "44001:80"      
    expose:
      - "4023"
      - "4022"
      - "4021"
      - "4020"
    links:
      - sql
    entrypoint: cmd /c "start /B powershell C:/sitecore/scripts/Watch-Directory.ps1 C:/src C:\inetpub\sc & powershell C:/sitecore/scripts/Watch-Directory.ps1 C:/docker-specific-files C:\inetpub\sc -ExcludeFiles @('Web.config','ConnectionStrings.config') & C:\\remote_debugger\\x64\\msvsmon.exe /noauth /anyuser /silent /nostatus /noclrwarn /nosecuritywarn /nofirewallwarn /nowowwarn /timeout:2147483646"
```

The Docker is working Ok, I can connect to it and see that the remote debugger is running and working.

But VS can't find any remote debugger like it is described in an article [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2019/01/30/debugging-docker-containers-attaching/)

What am I missing, what could be an issue?

Comment: I'm voting to move this question to sitecore.stackexchange.com

Comment: which topology were you trying to connect? Was it CD or CM? I am able to connect to the remote debugger in container, but I don't have any port exposed specified in docker-compose. Could you try to add 4024 as it's the default port used by remote debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use remote debugger for Visual Studio 2017 you have to expose port "4022" (you can find more at [MS docs: Remote Debugger Port Assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugger-port-assignments?view=vs-2019)).
According to the article which you mentioned in your question you have to map ports like that:

```
cd:
...
  ports:
    - "44002:80"
    - "4022:4022"
...
```

And you can remove "expose" sections from your Docker Compose file since such ports exposing is not needed.